# Convergence of integral with parameter

Tags: calculus

For which $t$ does the following integral converge?

$$\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{(1-\cos x)^t(1-x)^3}{\ln^2(1-x)}\,dx$$ where $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What've you tried?

Comment: Thank you well,ln(1-x)~x and cosx~x.Is this a good start?

Comment: @Ivan Beker $\cos x$ does not behave like $ x$ near zero.

Comment: sorry it is $1-x^2/2$

Comment: @Ivan Beker. Excellent. So what is the integrand in terms of $x$ (approximated) ?

Comment: $\frac{(1-x)^{t+3}}{x^2}$

Comment: No. Why are you replacing $\cos x$ by $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. As $x$ tends to $0^+$, you have
$$\frac{(1-\cos x)^t(1-x)^3}{\ln^2(1-x)} \sim \frac{(x^2/2)^t}{x^2}=\frac1{2^t}x^{2t-2}$$ your integral converges iff $t>\frac12$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Use series. It is necessary to see first two terms in $(1-x)^3/\ln^2(1-x)$.

Comment: Actually the term $(1-x)^3$ is irrelevant for the convergence of the integral.